# Traversing the Ordered List backwards returning each li text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I traverse an ordered list and return the text if I have a scenario where the user can click on a li element like Cat 1-2 and it returns all of the parent li's text into a string or an array.  If an array I can reverse the sort but eventually I need it to be a string.

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Cat 1
        <ul>
            <li>Cat 1-1
                <ul>
                    <li>Cat 1-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Cat 2
        <ul>
            <li>Cat 2-1
                <ul>
                    <li>Cat 2-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

if clicked on Cat 1-2 the desired result would be:
str = "Cat 1/Cat 1-1/Cat 1-2";

if clicked on Cat 2-1 the desired result would be:
str = "Cat 2/Cat 2-1";

What I would like to have is checkboxes on this where I could join all the selections into a string hierarchy like:
str = "Cat 1/Cat 1-1/Cat 1-2|Cat 2/Cat 2-1";

Comment: Definitely , that is possible. But have you written any code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here; I'll show a down and dirty method to get you rolling, then you can find a better way (maybe using textContent)...

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    var parents = $(this).add($(this).parents('li'))
        .map(function(){
            return $(this).clone().children().remove().end()
                   .text().replace(/\r|\n|^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
        })
        .toArray().join('/');
    alert(parents);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is any more efficient than Brad's method, but I started working on this earlier and it bugged me until I had it finished.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pUG6G/2/)

```
var ary = [];
$('li').click(function (e) {
    ary.push($.trim($(this).clone()
        .children()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text()));
    if ($(this).parents('ul').parent('li').length == 0) {
        console.log(ary.reverse().join('/'));
        ary = [];
    }
});
```